# Ubuntu18.10 - no sound after update

Tags: sound

I have been running the same set-up for a while but after the latest Ubuntu update I have no sound. I have tried all the fixes suggested on line. I have Pulse Audio (deleted and re-loaded) and it detects the sound output showing the sound card (AMD chip) and the meters move when I run test sound inputs (i.e. I don't think this is a 'Dummy output' problem) but no sound comes out of the speakers. I have tried different sources with no problems and triple checked that nothing is muted or disconnected so I am 99% certain this is a software issue created by the latest update. I've deleted timidity service and I've updated Chrome  (which for some reason stopped auto-updating). I'm stumped - anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get sound if you use another OS? You could try booting a "live USB" with another Ubuntu version or another Linux distro.

Comment: Already deleted and re-loaded alsamixer - no help - no muted outputs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package `sudo apt install alsamixer` and then simply type `alsamixer`. It will show if you have some muted outputs.

If this will not solve your problem, you can try this method also (this one was helpful for me):

`sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher` and replace string `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after updating to 20.04 LTS.  Tried all solutions suggested but still found I had to "sudo alsa force-reload pulseaudio" after each reboot.  Tracked down that on force-reload two processes were stopped and one (pulseaudio) was restarted.  Other mystery process was "timidity"  I had used this in the past but haven't for ages.  I uninstalled "timidity" and my problem went away.  My sound operates properly after reboot and no more "dummy output".

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, @RogerKauffman. Answer is cool, but the formatting... Could be separated into two paragraphs. :)